# Display error on while gettting multiple td id based value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my table with different value. While access td id based value through javascript it returns single value only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
      <td class="srno"> 1. </td>

      <td class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="9"></td>
      <td class="cname">11534420 </td>
      <td class="comName" id="9 ">student1 </td>
      <td scope="col" id="contactno" style="display:none;">123456789</td>
      <td scope="col" id="stuname" style="display:none;">student1</td>
      <td class="attendance"><select name="selattend">
      <option value="present">Present</option>
      <option value="absent">Absent</option>
      </select></td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="srno"> 2. </td>

      <td class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="10"></td>
      <td class="cname">14395673 </td>
      <td class="comName" id="10 ">student2 </td>
      <td scope="col" id="contactno" style="display:none;">123456780</td>
      <td scope="col" id="stuname" style="display:none;">student2</td>
      <td class="attendance"><select name="selattend">
      <option value="present">Present</option>
      <option value="absent">Absent</option>
      </select></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="srno"> 3. </td>

      <td class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="11"></td>
      <td class="cname">17256926 </td>
      <td class="comName" id="11 ">student3 </td>
      <td scope="col" id="contactno" style="display:none;">123456712</td>
      <td scope="col" id="stuname" style="display:none;">student3</td>
      <td class="attendance"><select name="selattend">
      <option value="present">Present</option>
      <option value="absent">Absent</option>
      </select></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my external javascript code is

```
function getvalue()
{
var contactno=document.getElementById("contactno").innerText;
    alert(contactno);
var stuname=document.getElementById("stuname").innerText;
    alert(stuname);
}
```

It returns first td id value only. How to get array of all id based td value get in javascript

Comment: you can't have multiple elements with the same ID, this will be invalid HTML, just use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with class selector instead and filter your data based on it or just make your function dynamic to receive `this` object so that it works.

Comment: How you are calling `getvalue()`?

Comment: onclick event onclick=getvalue()

Comment: is it possible to get all td value from absent value selected field list? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementById() method will always return only the first found DOM element, never a list! Please use querySelectorAll() method for such queries where you need multiple elements in your result.

Example:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#contactno');

for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].innerText)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
      <td class="srno"> 1. </td>

      <td class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="9"></td>
      <td class="cname">11534420 </td>
      <td class="comName" id="9 ">student1 </td>
      <td scope="col" id="contactno" style="display:none;">123456789</td>
      <td scope="col" id="stuname" style="display:none;">student1</td>
      <td class="attendance"><select name="selattend">
      <option value="present">Present</option>
      <option value="absent">Absent</option>
      </select></td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="srno"> 2. </td>

      <td class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="10"></td>
      <td class="cname">14395673 </td>
      <td class="comName" id="10 ">student2 </td>
      <td scope="col" id="contactno" style="display:none;">123456780</td>
      <td scope="col" id="stuname" style="display:none;">student2</td>
      <td class="attendance"><select name="selattend">
      <option value="present">Present</option>
      <option value="absent">Absent</option>
      </select></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="srno"> 3. </td>

      <td class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="11"></td>
      <td class="cname">17256926 </td>
      <td class="comName" id="11 ">student3 </td>
      <td scope="col" id="contactno" style="display:none;">123456712</td>
      <td scope="col" id="stuname" style="display:none;">student3</td>
      <td class="attendance"><select name="selattend">
      <option value="present">Present</option>
      <option value="absent">Absent</option>
      </select></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to get all td value from absent value selected field list?

Comment: and how to get that?